# Using sed, how do I delete all initial lines that match any of a set of patterns?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, centos7

I'm looking to use **sed** to delete all of the initial lines in a file that match a set of patterns. But, once none of the patterns are matched, the rest of the file should be passed through unmodified.

For example, if the patterns are:

```
^\s*#
^\s*$
```

Then for the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Some words

# The line above has spaces or tabs in it
    #
    # The above line has spaces before and after the #

main()
{ ... }

# Another comment
```

the sed script would generate:

```
main()
{ ... }

# Another comment
```

That is, in this case the set of patterns removes any *initial* Bash comments and, blank lines, and lines that just have whitespace in them.

While it might be interesting to hear how this might be done with other tools (such as `awk`), I am mainly interested in solutions involving `sed`.

I'm looking for a specific solution to the example above as well as any guidance as to how to generalize this for a set of arbitrary patterns.

My environment is:

- CentOS 7.3 (3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64)
- bash-4.2.46-21.el7_3.x86_64
- sed-4.2.2-5.el7.x86_64

Comment: Are you OK with using `head` or `tail`?

Comment: I've updated the example above to show that lines that are past a line that doesn't match the patterns are to be preserved. @MadPhysicist - you tempt me. Maybe yes and I'm curious as to how you'd do that with arbitrary regexes.

Comment: My plan was to stop after the first non match, tee it into `wc -l`, then `tail` the remainder. This is a stupid solution, but I don't know enough sed to do what @aragaer did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete lines that do match, but once you get past all the patterns, just print the rest using the loop `:done;n;bdone`

Here's the example:

test.c:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Some words

# The line above has spaces or tabs in it
    #
    # The above line has spaces before and after the #

DELETEME

main()
DELETEME - should stay
{ ... }



$ sed '/^\s*#/d; /DELETEME/d; /^\s*$/d; :done;n;bdone' test.c 
main()
DELETEME - should stay
{ ... }
```

Comment: Very nice and extra points for demonstrating additional patterns (DELETEME). I've tested it and it works perfectly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if I wanted to apply extra sed patterns to the balance of the file (at and after the first non-matching line), could I do that in the same sed script? I can certainly pipe into another sed to do that.  Thanks again! I just changed the expression to `:done; s/^/xxx/; n; bdone` as a demonstration of adding additional sed transforms and that works. Do you agree?